# Postgres unique index says duplicate exists on freshly deleted row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database in which I'm refreshing data periodically. Most of the time it works, but sometimes I have issues with a unique index.

**Minimal example**

```
create table test_table (
  id int
);
create unique index test_table_unique on test_table(id);
```

(I know, in this case it should be a primary key, but for the sake of example, please bear with me.)

Now, every hour, I do something like this:

```
begin;
delete from test_table;
insert into test_table (id) values (1), (2), (3)...
commit;
```

As I said, most of the time it will just work fine. However, sometimes postgres complains about a duplicate entry in the unique index.

```
error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint test_table_unique
detail: "Key (id)=(2) already exists."
```

**My real database**

In my actual table, I'm using JSON payloads, and the unique index is made on fields of that json payload. In particular, the error details is as follows:

```
create table if not exists source (
    id serial primary key,
    payload jsonb not null
);

create unique index if not exists source_index_and_id on source ((payload->>'_index'), (payload->>'_id'));

error details: "Key ((payload ->> '_index'::text), (payload ->> '_id'::text))=(companies, AC9860) already exists."
```

I'm confident there is no actual duplicate data. I'm deleting everything for a particular `->>_index`, and the `->>_id` is unique in my source data.

My understanding is that if I delete rows from a table, the indices will be updated **before** the next statements are executed. But it doesn't seem to be the case. I've found that it helps (not sure if it actually solves the issue) to commit the changes after the delete, and before the inserts.

```
begin;
delete...
commit;

begin;
insert...
commit;
```

What's happening here?

Comment: I don't know if it solves your problem, but the delete query should not have *, i.e. "delete * from test_table;" -> "delete from test_table;"

Comment: Indeed, it's a bad example. The actual delete query is correct though :)

Comment: I am pretty sure this is some kind of user error.  Maybe you have launched two copies of your process which are simultaneously trying to insert the same data.  Anyway, the minimal example isn't really an example if it fails to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @jjanes Pretty sure this is not user error. I've had this both on my local environment where I run things manually only, and on the production server where they are ran on an hourly cron.

Comment: What is the full version number (like from `select version();`)?

Comment: On Azure: `PostgreSQL 11.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`, and on WSL: `PostgreSQL 11.12 (Debian 11.12-0+deb10u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit`

Answer (score 2):

The only options how this could happen are

- the deleting transaction rolled back
- concurrent transactions inserted new rows after you deteted the original ones
- the inserting transaction inserts the same key twice
- the inserting transaction is accidentally run before the deleting one

Comment: None of that happens. I'm runnig these instructions sequentially in the same transaction, from the same script, manually from a shell. I'm also absolutely sure the keys are not duplicated (checked it). There's absolutely no chance any of that happened.

Comment: Check again. It must be a trivial mistake. Are you using PostgreSQL or some fork of it?

Comment: psql (13.3, server 11.11). I guarantee you, it's not a mistake. In fact, adding a `commit; begin;` between the delete and the insert fixes the issue.

Comment: But that is not how PostgreSQL behaves. If you run the statements you show in a single transaction, and there is nothing else going on in your database. this cannot happen.

Comment: And yet it did. Both times the disk was under stress: slow day on my local WSL environment, and on production it happened when the disk was almost full. I suspect there may be something weird with disk caching.

Answer (score -2):

PostGreSQL is not a real relational DBMS and does not match rule 7 of Codd's Rule about functional set operations.

Contrary to other RDBMS PostGreSQL delete rows one by one and this lack of functionality conduct to have sometime fantom key violation.

In my paper that compare PostGreSQL to MS SQL Server I made a test that show this evidence ([§ 7 – The hard way to udpates unique values](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/))

Comment: Interesting. Though in your example you make an update, and in that one operation there's a conflict. I could see where this is an issue, but I feel like (hope?) my case here is different, since it's two different operations.

Comment: @adpyct You can safely ignore this answer.

Comment: You are right that UPDATEs on unique values behave differently in PostgreSQL and sql serVer. But the question is about DELETE so your rant about different behaviour is irrelevant here